# Scroll event on a ListView in ExtJS3.x

Tags: listview, extjs, scroll

I have a ListView in ExtJs3.1 and I have been trying to listen on the 'scroll' event. Most examples I've seen for controls such as panels specify the following:

> panel.body.on('scroll', function(a, b,
>   c){
>       //put logic here });

now the problem with the ListView is that it doesn't have a body attribute, not that I have seen in fireBug. I tried appending the event onto the innerBody of the listView but obviously this did not do anything.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

I am pretty sure I am missing something very basic but I have spent about 2 hours pouring through Docs and Source files now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround!

Although the listView does not expose a body attribute as such, that isn't to say we cannot access the body. using CSS selectors I got the body of the listView by doing the following:

> var body =
>   listView.el.child('.x-list-body');

That body variable is of XType Ext.Element and I can now listen on the scroll event as well as called the scroll method and the scollIntoView method.

Answer (score 0):

is the listview itself scrolling or the panel's body?